# How to fill out empty spaces by aligned list items

Tags: html, css

I want to align list items so no empty space is left between without using any JavaScript plugins (like Masonry). Elements come aligned in order and are inserted into list.

Example: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wucuvezovo/edit?html,css,output)

HTML:

```
<ul class="example-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="three">3</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.example-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
}

.example-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.three {
  height: 100px;
}
```

From the example: 2 should fill out the empty space above it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS Columns would seem to the option or flex-columns

Comment: Hey ! I seems to have found a solution... Posting as an answer...

Comment: Possible solution: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/cys2eoxv), since que doesn't have clear requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution

https://jsfiddle.net/43ofd9co/

We can use CSS columns to create the effect... check this above link... I have created the fiddle.

```
    div{
            -moz-column-count: 2;
            -moz-column-gap: 10px;
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
            column-count: 2;
            column-gap: 10px;
            width: 480px;
    }

    div a{
          display: inline-block;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          width: 100%;
          border:2px solid #333;}

    .height{height:100px;}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="#">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#" class="height">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#" class="height">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#" class="height">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#" class="height">Your Content goes here...</a>
<a href="#">Your Content goes here...</a>
</div>
```

Check this for reference: http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

NB: This solution does not work in IE9 and below.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution that is used by google+

Dividing the content physically in several columns.
For example:
https://plus.google.com/+Scobleizer

```
<div class="ona Fdb bsa" style="width:900px">
    <div class="Ypa jw Yc am">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Ypa jw Yc am">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know, do they use js for it.
Anyway it's possible without js.